# Unable to ping, nothing except askubuntu opening

Tags: wireless, 13.04

Everything was going fine, and there were no new installs or updates. But suddenly my wireless started giving me issues.

It connects fine, but I am unable to open anything (not even google), or ping anything. The network strength shows just 1 bar (weak signal) even though it should be strong (am near the router). Sometimes when it does work, its too slow to load the complete page.

Strangely though, I am having absolutely no problems browsing and posting to askubuntu.com!

Comment: Check your DNS settings?

Comment: Yep DNS is all fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seemed to have been a region-wide issue with the ISP. Everything is up and running now.